# Perspective Transform using paper

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I've got an image from phone camera which have a paper inside it. In the image are also, some coordinates marked to get the distance between them. Since the aspect ratio of paper is known in advance (0.7072135785007072), I want to correct the distortion so that the whole image looks as if it's taken from the top view. I collect the four corners of the paper and apply opencv `getPerspectiveTransform` as follows:

```
pts1 = [[ 717.,  664.],
[1112.,  660.],
[1117., 1239.],
[ 730., 1238.]]

ratio=0.7072135785007072
cardH=math.sqrt((pts1[2][0]-pts1[1][0])*(pts1[2][0]-pts1[1][0])+(pts1[2][1]-pts1[1][1])*(pts1[2][1]-pts1[1][1]))
cardW=ratio*cardH;
pts2 = np.float32([[pts1[0][0],pts1[0][1]], [pts1[0][0]+cardW, pts1[0][1]], [pts1[0][0]+cardW, pts1[0][1]+cardH], [pts1[0][0], pts1[0][1]+cardH]])

M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)
```

with this matrix `M` I'm transforming the whole image as follows:

```
transformed = np.zeros((image.shape[1], image.shape[0]), dtype=np.uint8);
dst = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, transformed.shape)
_ = cv2.rectangle(dst, (pts2[0][0], pts2[0][1]), (int(pts2[2][0]), int(pts2[2][1])), (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

The problem with this is that it's correcting the perspective of paper but distorting the overall image. I don't know why. The input image is [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dWvuq7qMBV7rVosWaTuYOvP411KIeP_L) and the corresponding output image is [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aRUP-uc9ehdtNC2TekuM9ktAGFKh8Y40). In the input image point M and O and aligned horizontally, but to my surprise after transforming the overall image the point M and O are no longer aligned horizontally, why is that happening ?

Comment: is the paper in the dame plane as the "overall image"?  Perpective transformations describe plane transformations

Comment: the other thing are errors. If you try to extrapolate a plane from a small area, tiny errors (wrong pixels/positions) will become big errors in further distance from you reference position.

Comment: @Micka Yes, the paper is in the same plane as the overall image. How to get a transformation matrix to reduce the error for the points farther away from the reference ?